# Error in match.arg(ci_style) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: sjplot

I'm wondering if anyone would have insight as to why I am receiving this error:

> Error in match.arg(ci_style) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

It only seems to happen when I ask for a type = "pred" plot.

The exact same command works fine on a different machine at home. The differences I can see are that the machine where the command works fine was updated to Sonoma, and a slightly older version of R.

Thanks!

R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.7.10

```
lm(OBP ~ Avg, data = base100)
yaya <- lm(OBP ~ Avg, data = base100)
plot_model(yaya, type = "pred")
```

> Error in match.arg(ci_style) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Comment: I have the same isse, but when using `type = "eff"`. I think there might be some conflict with another package, but I am not finding it. The issue should be somewhere in `sjPlot:::plot_type_eff()`...

Comment: For me, explicitly ading the predictor helped. So maybe it works for you as well when adding `terms = "Avg"` in the `plot_model()`-call?

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. Thanks Zoe, I guess it is some sort of conflict and I also could not find it.